# Netflix ICE and librarian-chef - The package archive has too many children

Tags: chef-infra, netflix, chef-recipe, ice

I'm trying to deploy opscode "Netflix ICE" cookbook. 
ENV rvm ruby 2.0.0
librarian-chef 0.0.1

Getting the following error during running librarian-chef install:

```
*[Librarian] Unpacking tmp/librarian/cache/source/chef/site/877777683730772c/artifact/version-uri/2352964421717b53/package.tar.gz to tmp/librarian/scratch/7924de8184850fe3ec287a571d2115a3
```

/Users/seva/git/chef/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/librarian-chef-0.0.1/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:271:in `unpack_package!': The package archive has too many children! (RuntimeError)*

Tried to define both, opscode and git, Netflix ICE repo in Cheffile.
Also package.tar.gz file is consistent and I'm able to unpack it successfully

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well and found that this is actually a problem with the artifact cookbook.  I found that if I explicitly add the following line to my Cheffile I was able to run librarian-chef without issue:

```
cookbook 'artifact', '1.9.0'
```